# Integrate DLL compiled with Intel C++ Compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, compiler-construction, intel

Is it possible to integrate into an application compiled with Visual Studio compiler a DLL compiled with Intel C++ Compiler ?

Are there some special settings to pay attention to for integration?

Comment: What is the calling convention for the DLL?  https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/433526

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/566086/Use-Intel-Cplusplus-compiler-with-Cplusplus-CLI

Comment: @RobertHarvey what is calling convention?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention

Comment: how do I know the calling convention for the DLL ?

Comment: It all depends on what the DLL exports. Unless you can supply some more details about the DLL, nobody can offer you very specific advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some compatibility options for using Intel C++ Compiler while being compatible with the Visual Studio framework, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-compatibility-with-microsoft-visual-c

> Compatibility Options
>
> The following Intel® Compiler options provide compatibility with
> different versions of Microsoft Visual C++:
>
> /Qvc8 Microsoft Visual C++ 2005
>
> /Qvc9 Microsoft Visual C++ 2008
>
> /Qvc10
> Microsoft Visual C++ 2010